# How to make the simplest <div>-like transparent container/layer in AndEngine?

Tags: android, positioning, containers, andengine, transparent

I would simply like to have an *Entity*, *Rectangle* or something that would serve as a plain container for other *Sprites*.

Positioning purposes is what I need it for... I need to be able to **set this container's width** and **position**.

I have tried with *Rectangle*, but it seems to hide absolutely everything behind it (with a lower Z-index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the alpha of the Rectangle to "see" what's underneath it. Something like

```
myRect = new Rectangle(x, (CAMERA_HEIGHT - 480 + 100) / 2, size, size, vboManager);

myRect.setAlpha(0);

scene.attachChild(myRect);
```